# Perl script to remove repeating header/trailer in file

Tags: perl

I have created a perl script to merge 10 file in one. Each file has Keyword header/Trailer in file. So merged file has multiple header and trailer keyword. but I require the header and trailer to be present in start and end of merged file only.

Example:

File1.txt -->

```
Header
Content1
Trailer
```

File2.txt -->

```
Header
Content2
Trailer
```

Merged.txt (currently) -->

```
Header
Content1
Trailer
Header
Content2
Trailer
```

Merged.txt (Required) -->

```
Header
Content1
Content2
Trailer
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
perl -ne 'if ($. == 1 || eof) { print ; next };
          print unless /Header|Trailer/' merged.txt
```

That should print the first and last line regardless of contents, and every line that doesn't contain either Header or Trailer.

Use perl's `-i` option if you want it to modify the input file rather than print to stdout (but, you know, I wouldn't recommend doing that until after verifying that the output is what you want - e.g. redirect to another file and use `diff` to compare with the original).

---

With a small modification, this can also be used to concatenate any number of input files, removing any "Header" or "Trailer" lines whilst still ensuring that the first line of the first file and the last line of the last file will always be printed (even if they contain "Header" or "Trailer").  For example:

```
$ perl -ne 'if ($. == 1 || (! @ARGV && eof)) { print ; next };
            print unless /Header|Trailer/' file1.txt file2.txt 
Header
Content1
Content2
Trailer
```

The first statement tests for two conditions:

1. `$. == 1` tests if the current line is the first input line
2. `(! @ARGV && eof)` tests if the current line is the last line of the last file.

   Evaluating `@ARGV` in scalar context returns the number of elements in the array of command-line arguments (filenames), and each filename will be `shift`-ed out of the array as it is opened for processing, decrementing the count. The result will be 0 (false) on the last file.  Negating that with `!` results in true when reading the last file.

   AND-ing that with `eof` (true if we are the end of the current file) will only be true on the last line of the last file.

If either of these conditions is true, then the current line is printed.

The second statement prints the current line unless it matches either "Header" or "Trailer".

BTW, `unless` is a perl syntax equivalent to `if !` ("if not") - sometimes it's more natural to say "if not X then do Y", other times it's more natural to say "do Y unless X".  Both are functionally the same.  Both can be placed either before or after the statement you want to conditionally execute.  You can probably guess that perl's principal designer & author (Larry Wall) is a linguist.

From `man perlsyn`:

> `if` executes the statement once if and only if the condition is true.
>
> `unless` is the opposite, it executes the statement unless the condition is true (that is, if the condition is false).

---

The `{print; next}` in the first conditional isn't strictly necessary - it's to prevent the first or last line from being printed twice if they **don't** contain "Header" or "Trailer". If you're certain that will never be the case, the first statement could be simplified a little to:

for the first one-liner:

```
print if ($. == 1 || eof);
```

or (for the second one-liner):

```
print if ($. == 1 || (! @ARGV && eof));
```

Comment: I am new to perl, Can you help me how to add following in my script

$ perl -ne 'if ($. == 1 || (! @ARGV && eof)) { print ; next };
            print unless /Header|Trailer/' file1.txt file2.txt 

as of now my script has created file1.txt at location where it resides. I want the above code to execute automatically once file1.txt is created

Comment: automatic execution is way beyond the scope of a simple text processing script.  you'd need to either schedule execution at a particular time or time(s) with `cron` or `systemd.timer`, or use `inotify` to monitor the directory and execute a script when file1.txt is created.  In either case, that would be the subject of another question, not a minor detail answerable in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do:

```
perl -i -lne 'print unless ($_ eq "Header" && $. > 1) || ($_ eq "Trailer" && !eof)' your-file
```

Can also be done with `sed`:

```
sed -e 1b -e '$b' -e '/^Header$/d' -e '/^Trailer$/d' your-file
```

Some `sed` implementations can do perl-style inplace editing, some (most) with `-i`, some (FreeBSD and derivatives including macos) with `-i ''`

You can remove the redundant headers/trailers upon merging with:

```
perl -lne '
  if (eof) {
    $n++;  # counts files
    close ARGV; # resets $.
    next if @ARGV; # if there are more files to process
  }
  print unless $. == 1 && $n # first list and not first file
  ' file<->.txt(n)
```

(the `file<->.txt(n)` to match on `file<number>.txt` sorted `n`umerically (so `file10.txt` sorts between `file9.txt` and `file11.txt`, not between `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` as it would otherwise) requires the `zsh` shell)

Or with GNU `sed` (and still `zsh`):

```bash
() {
  head -n1 < $1
  sed -s -- '1d;$d' "$@"
  tail -n1 < $argv[-1]
} file<->.txt(n)
```